# get 504 error from credentials provider from next auth when I try to sign in after deploy in vercel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, next-auth

I have been struggling with this error about one week  and in dev mode everything is working
perfectly but when I deploy and want to sign in via next auth credentials provider I get error and I do not know where it comes from?
I checked everything and set All env variable in vercel dashboard but it seems my backend has not deploy correctly or something is wrong with my next-auth config
[image]

[image]

this is my [...nextauth].js

```
 CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",

      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const payload = {
          email: credentials.email,
          password: credentials.password,
        };
        const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/api/auth/signin`, {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(payload),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        });

        const user = await res.json();

        if (res.ok && user) {
          return user;
        }

        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {},
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user };
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session = token;
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin",
```

/auth/signin.js

```
 <button
          className="border-2 w-[200px] h-[40px] uppercase"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            signIn("credentials", {
              email: emailRef.current,
              password: passwordRef.current,
            });
          }}
        >
          Sign in
        </button>
```

Comment: have you find a solution to this? I am experiencing the same issue at the moment

Comment: yes, my problem because of I was using mongodb to store user data in /api/auth/signin and I had not add the  ip and access to website after deployed, so because of that I got error in credentials to retrieve user data from mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone has this 504 problem when signing in with google for example. Make sure that the deploy has access to the database. In my case MongoDB was blocking the IP.

Answer (score 0):

So I was facing this exact problem in a Strapi and Nextjs project. I fixed it by removing the trailing "/" in NEXTAUTH_URL eg. `https://example.com` instead of `https://example.com/`. Then make sure to redeploy in Vercel.